# Rails 3.2.5 Stylesheet Not Being Applied - Newbie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am learning Rails from "Agile Web Development With Rails" (4th edition, Rails 3) and I am having trouble getting a stylesheet to apply. To quickly take you through what I have done so far, I first generated a scaffold:

```
 rails generate scaffold Product title:string description:text image_url:string price:decimal
```

Then of course:

```
 rake db:migrate
```

I then used the db/seeds.rb file to load some data into the products table. When I loaded localhost:3000/products, everything was working great. Now, I copied the stylesheet code the book provides to the products.css.scss file generated by the scaffold:

```
.products {
  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  table tr td {
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
 .list_image {
    width:  60px;
    height: 70px;
  }
  .list_description {
    width: 60%;

    dl {
      margin: 0;
    }
    dt {
      color:        #244;
      font-weight:  bold;
      font-size:    larger;
    }
    dd {
      margin: 0;
    }
  }
  .list_actions {
     font-size:    x-small;
     text-align:   right;
     padding-left: 1em;
  }
  .list_line_even {
    background:   #e0f8f8;
  }
  .list_line_odd {
    background:   #f8b0f8;
  }
}
```

Now, when I load localhost:3000/products, the stylesheet is not being applied.I can see the stylesheet in inspect element, but it is not applying. I have tried everything imaginable. Firstly, I made sure this line of code was in my application.html.erb:

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
```

Given that my new stylesheet (products.css.scss) is in the assets/stylesheets/ directory, it should be loaded. When I inspect element on localhost:3000/products, I actually see the stylesheet there, but it is not being applied. the next thing I tried was running:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

No success. After deleting the public/assets directory, I made sure this line of code was in my config/application.rb file:

```
 config.assets.enabled = true
```

It was. Next, I headed over to my assets/stylesheet/application.css file and tried adding this line of code:

```
*= require products
```

Once again, no success. Lastly, I tried restarting my server to see if there was an effect. Failure again. I am at dead end here. Please, I would appreciate any and all input on this matter as I am so burnt-out and frustrated with this matter.

Comment: I think you have asked the same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987100/stylesheet-error-ruby-on-rails-newbie) a couple of hours ago... someone told you to remove the space on line 15 and you said it has solved the problem... If you are stil having the same problem I think you should reopen your previous question... if I am wrong, sorry about that...

Comment: No, its a different question. Sorry if there was any confusion. My previous question was in regard to getting the stylesheet loaded. Now it is loading (I am not getting an error), but it is not applying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just spent an hour figuring out the answer, since been having the exact same issue myself. go to your application.css.sass and make sure it has

```
/* ...
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*/
```

in it. this auto loads all the other .css.sass in apps/assets/stylesheets, then precompiles them into public/assets/stylesheets to be 1 statis css file, and that is being served to your browser.

Comment: You meant application.css? because I do have those lines. But doesn't /* characters are for commenting lines?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this will work but worth a shot, try removing .css, just keep products.scss.  Also get a very simple style going and see if it works.  Or even inline it to see.